# limit access to SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions

I have a site collection with a subsite. I am storing a roadmap and some other project management documents within a document library in my subsite. I would like to share that document library with an internal user, but I don’t want her to see anything else – just that document library. I don’t want her to see any other parts of the site. Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

1. Go to Site Settings > Site Permissions
2. Remove the user from all groups (click on Check Permissions to see what permissions she has on your site).
3. Go to the document library and click on the Library tab in the
   ribbon.
4. Click on Shared With (far to the right)
5. Click on ADVANCED
6. Click on Stop Inheriting Permissions, confirm with Ok
7. Click on Grant
8. Permissions and give the user the appropriate rights (read, edit
   etc.)

EDIT:
This is for a SharePoint 2013 site. Sorry for that. I dont have a SharePoint 2010 site available right now so I cant give you the exact steps, but the concept is still the same:

1. Remove the users permissions to the site.
2. Stop inheriting permissions for the document library
3. Grant the user permissions to the documet library